# Tricky Query: Forecasting Dates

Tags: mysql

Good Day.

I am blocked by this problem in my SQL query:

Given the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `Forecasted_Sales_tcl` (
`DEALER_id` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`SALES_period` date NOT NULL,
`TYPE` int(2) NOT NULL,
`UNIT_SALES` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`HEAD_OFFICE_CODE` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL
PRIMARY KEY (`DEALER_CODE`,`SALES_MONTH`,`TYPE`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b780c

I need to generate the possible sales charges in the coming months.
For example I have plotted an outbound sales (unit_sales ) for a month 
(SALES_period) "June 2012" on a store. I am expecting some service charges 
type A on Aug 2012, type B on Oct 2012, type C on Dec 2012. I Also
have some out bound sales on some different months on different stores.

I am trying to generate a report something like this:

```
  Period  |charge A  | charge B |charge C | store_id
2012-Jan  |    X     |     Y    |    Z    |   (id)
2012-Feb  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Mar  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Apr  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-May  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Jun  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Jul  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Aug  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Sep  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Oct  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Nov  |    :     |     :    |    :    : 
2012-Dec  |    :     |     :    |    :    :
```

X is total the unit_sales (2 Months Ago) for the store (id)
Y is total the unit_sales (4 Months Ago) for the store (id) 
Z is total the unit_sales (6 Months Ago) for the store (id)

---

Given the said data on the sql fiddle and some parameters:
Generate Report:
From: 2012-06
To  : 2013-07

```
  Period  | Dealer Id  |  CHARGE X |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C | 
 2012-06  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2012-07  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2012-08  |    0001    |       100 |         0 |         0 |
 2012-09  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2012-10  |    0001    |         0 |       100 |         0 |
 2012-11  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2012-12  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |       100 |
 2013-01  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-02  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-03  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-04  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-05  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-06  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-07  |    0001    |         0 |         0 |         0 |

  Period  | Dealer Id  |  CHARGE A |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C | 
 2012-06  |    0002    |         0 |        10 |         2 |
 2012-07  |    0002    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2012-08  |    0002    |        10 |         0 |         0 |
 2012-09  |    0002    |        18 |         0 |         0 |
 2012-10  |    0002    |         5 |        10 |         0 |
 2012-11  |    0002    |         0 |        18 |         0 |
 2012-12  |    0002    |         0 |         5 |        10 |
 2013-01  |    0002    |         0 |         0 |        18 |
 2013-02  |    0002    |         0 |         0 |         5 |
 2013-03  |    0002    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-04  |    0002    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-05  |    0002    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-06  |    0002    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
 2013-07  |    0002    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
```

> > On This 10 is for the Sales (2012-04) while
> >                2 is for the sales (2012-02)
> >
> > ```
> >   Period  | Dealer Id  |  CHARGE A |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C | 
> >  2012-06  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2012-07  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2012-08  |    0003    |         1 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2012-09  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2012-10  |    0003    |         0 |         1 |         0 |
> >  2012-11  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2012-12  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         1 |
> >  2013-01  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2013-02  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2013-03  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2013-04  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2013-05  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2013-06  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> >  2013-07  |    0003    |         0 |         0 |         0 |
> > ```
> >
> > Master Report

```
           |               2012-06             |               2012-07             |               2012-08             |               2012-09             |               2012-10             |               2012-11             |
Dealer ID  |  CHARGE A |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C |  CHARGE A |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C |  CHARGE A |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C |  CHARGE A |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C |  CHARGE A |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C |  CHARGE A |  CHARGE B |  CHARGE C |
001        |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |       100 |         0 |         0 |        18 |         0 |         0 |         0 |       100 |         0 |         0 |        18 |         0 |
002        |         0 |        10 |         2 |         0 |         0 |         0 |        10 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |        10 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |
003        |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         1 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         1 |         0 |         0 |         0 |         0 |
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hum... that's quite tricky and I'm having a bit of a headache trying to understand correctly the question. But it looks like an interesting one, could you create a [sqlfiddle](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsqlfiddle.com%2F&ei=5JvcT5bCIbCM0wWxg8jNCg&usg=AFQjCNFm12TxaUOyr1fCpsH3njbgA9q20A) with some data and add an expected result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks for the SQLFiddle ! It's a **really nasty** report you're trying to achieve here :D

The closest I can get to (while using decent SQL) is this:

```
SELECT
  DEALER_ID,
  DATE,
  -- Next 3 rows feature the trick to transpose lines to columns.
  SUM(IF(CHARGE = 'A', UNIT_SALES, 0)) as CHARGE_A,
  SUM(IF(CHARGE = 'B', UNIT_SALES, 0)) as CHARGE_B,
  SUM(IF(CHARGE = 'C', UNIT_SALES, 0)) as CHARGE_C
FROM (

SELECT -- Create a row for each charge A.
  DEALER_id,
  'A' as CHARGE,
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(SALES_PERIOD, INTERVAL 2 MONTH), "%Y-%m") as DATE,
  UNIT_SALES
FROM forecasted_sales_tcl

UNION

SELECT -- Create a row for each charge B.
  DEALER_id,
  'B' as CHARGE,
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(SALES_PERIOD, INTERVAL 4 MONTH), "%Y-%m") as DATE,
  UNIT_SALES
FROM forecasted_sales_tcl

UNION

SELECT -- Create a row for each charge C.
  DEALER_id,
  'C' as CHARGE,
  DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(SALES_PERIOD, INTERVAL 6 MONTH), "%Y-%m") as DATE,
  UNIT_SALES
FROM forecasted_sales_tcl

) T
WHERE DATE >= "2012-06" AND DATE <= "2013-07"
GROUP BY DEALER_ID, DATE
ORDER BY DEALER_ID, DATE;
```

That gives you exactly what you want (and point out some mistakes in your fake output by the way :p) except that it doesn't generate the empty rows and that's where I stop for decency sake.

I don't say it's not possible but it becomes really ugly to **generate it**. If you really want to get into it, the first (and most difficult) job is to write a SQL query that generates a single column output:

```
DATE
2012-06
2012-07
2012-08
(...)
2013-06
2013-07
```

That could be a nice question to ask on SO :p

For curiosity sake you could have a look at this other trick:

```
SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row, t.* FROM some_table t, (SELECT @row := 0) r
```

Anyway, if you really want to get the ouput with the empty rows, the simplest way is to have another table filled with the periods. Next [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) finishes the job.

For the Master Report it is exactly the same pattern (and I'll be glad to help you with it if needed) **but** I strongly discourage you from doing this in SQL as it's not really its job. The transposition will be really ugly, and utterly not parameterizable (spelling ?).

I don't know what you're using to ouput the report but you should look at proper BI Tools for this business. From memory, Jasper Reports, BIRT...

Well, enjoy SQL :p

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply, I'll give feed back by Monday =) . Again, my sincere thanks.